# How to get correct format of coordinates for export to geojson from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, geojson

I've created a custom map in QGIS with a few shapefiles. I'm using leaflet.js to render the map and the shapefile points and everything lines up correctly. The CRS is set to 4326.

When I export the shapefiles as geojson from QGIS, the coordinates are huge and look something like this: `9949941.925330460071564, -12405330.17722519300878`

Leaflet is expecting coordinates that look like this: `82.9687,63.2336`

Anyone have any insight into resolving this problem?

Comment: Quick clarification, I want to export the shapefiles as geojson to zoom to specific coordinates on the prerendered map.

Comment: Looks like your original shapefiles are in projection that is in metres/feet need to reproject into WGS84 then your will get the expected decimal degrees.

Comment: When I right click on a shapefile > Set Layer CRS.. it's currently set to 'WGS 84' and 'EPSG:4326'. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That is what the layer is set to, but the data is obviously ot EPSG:4326. Do you have a .prj file for your shapefile? You can look into it with any text editor.

Comment: Yes I do, this is the contents of one of my shapefile's .prj: GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

Comment: Ok, thats correct. But what do you get if you rightclick on the layer ->properties, Metadata tab? The extent of the layer should be within +-90/180.

Comment: It is definitely not, From the Metadata tab: In layer spatial reference system units : xMin,yMin -4509052.65,-15369980.57 : xMax,yMax 14624578.38,13750373.80

Comment: These coordinates look like EPSG:3857.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to change the layer CRS with Rightclick ->`Set Layer CRS` to `EPSG:3857`. To verify that your data is in the correct place you can load the openlayers plugin with Google or Openstreetmap background.

For Geojson export, the target CRS **must** be `EPSG:4326`. You have to set that manually when using Rightclick->`Save As...`.

Comment: Yes! You have saved the day.

Comment: and how to export a geojson file with lat and long coordinates for polygon shapefile? TY